# Copy Table Schema and Data From server Database to local Database in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Copy Table Schema and Data From server Database to local Database in SQL Server..
i have tried some solutions from google..I got this type of query

```
Select * into DestinationDB.dbo.tableName from SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable
```

but this query is for copy local db to local db... i wanna copy server databse table data from local db table...

```
like my Server Name:--xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
login:-xxxxxx
password:-xxxxxx
```

How to do this???can anyone help me Please????

Comment: you are looking for backup,search for backup  and restore it in local server

Comment: or generate scripts or linked servers

Comment: I already made the backup from database with table,sp,functions but without data..now i want to copy the only table data from server database to local database..the database has huge amount of data so i cant make scripts..

Comment: If you can add the source server as a linked server on the destination, then copying the data is as easy as `insert into db.dbo.table select source.db.dbo.table`.  Otherwise, creating a backup on the source and restoring it on the destination seems like the best way to go.

Comment: how to copy he source server as a linked server on the destination can you explain it in details please???

Comment: Management Studio has a data import/export wizard built in. Right-click the database, choose "Tasks -> Export Data" and away you go.

Answer (score 0):

Use OPENROWSET

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

SELECT a.*
INTO DestinationDB.dbo.tableName
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=Server1;Trusted_Connection=no;';username;password,
     'SELECT * from SourceDB.dbo.SourceTable') AS a;

Naz